# Expo - Help modifying build.gradle

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas, expo-build

I'm currently working on an expo + react-native app.

We are working with a third party that has provided us with a react-native SDK. The SDK works great, except that in order to make use of one of its features, I am instructed to add a dependency to build.gradle as `implementation com.x.x.x:v`

I can modify my build.gradle directly if I build the app locally. However, we build the app on eas as part of our cicd pipeline so during this stage I don't have direct access to modify build.gradle.

How can I add this Android dependency?

Answer (score 0):

If you have manual steps for how to modify your native projects, then I strongly encourage you to NOT modify the native project but to instead [build a Config Plugin](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/config-plugin-and-native-module-tutorial/) (that is, use Expo's JavaScript API for modifying generated native projects).

This way you stay with the very strong benefits of having Expo manage your "native projects", including future upgrades to XCode/Android Studio and Expo SDKs.  If you go into "bare workflow" mode, then you are responsible for maintaining the native projects forever.